# How to Import Data from Publication list to a Data Extension Automatically

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have data stored in Publication lists, and I want to import this data into a data extension automatically.

How and what method will be useful to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) `_ListSubscribers` and a query activity to query the data into a data extension. The ListID is found in the properties tab of the list. Put it in an Automation Studio automation to automate it.

Comment: Hi Jackson- Thanks for your help. I will let you know if it will face any problem.

Comment: Please select as accepted answer

Comment: Hello, @Jackson it works. Thank you very much!